# With vs In. Which one is the appropriate for the following situation?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Which one of the following is grammatically correct?
There is a failure in / with the sensor.

Comment: Both can be correct, depending on the context.

Comment: If this is being used in an official document and the complete sentence would be,
Use a map based value, when there is a failure in/with the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

In this context *With* is a more generic way of saying that there is a failure.
*In* implies there is a specific failure within the sensor, for example the sensor is made of multiple components and one of those failed.